# Performance monitor and system info viewer for Ubuntu

Tags: monitoring, system-monitor

I saw that someone made a rather cool chrome app (which I prefer not to use), here: https://github.com/beaufortfrancois/cog-chrome-app

I was wondering do we have an equivalent gnome extension or even software that displays, CPU/GPU/Motherboard/HDD/SSD temperatures, processor/memory utilisation and hardware info.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: You might check out `conky`. Install it with `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install conky-all`. It requires a fair amount of setup, but many examples exist, and you can make it as beautiful as you wish. Search here on AU for "conky" for more info. Google "conky" for more info. Also see https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-conky-themes-for-linux/

Comment: I tried conky myself but it seemed clunky and built into the background of the desktop, those themes really makes them look real good.

Is there one that pops up in its own window/app container? Been trying to do one that is opaque. The Automatik theme is wonderful, just edit the transparency for some reason (I can't move the widgets after pressing Alt+Mouse either).

Comment: I'm not a Conky expert, so I can't provide more specific detail, other than pointing you in that direction. Enjoy!